Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:firebase_auth]
I tried all the changes suggested in documentation & stack overflow but still not able to solve the issue.
My build.gradle looks like this ;
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.with_flutter"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = 23
        minSdkVersion = 23
        targetSdk = 23
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

Updated the local.properties flie also:
flutter.minSdkVersion=23
flutter.targetSdkVersion=23
Is there any other way to resolve this?

Try not rebuilding the project after you have saved these changes to build.gradle, when the rebuild button (vs code) appears at the bottom right of the screen
